# In Calculus, why is function defined the way it is?

Tags: calculus, functions

I was reading "Richard Courant, Fritz John - Introduction to Calculus and Analysis". In it, there is the passage:

"Logically, we are not restricted to such geometrically or mechanically generated functions. Any rule by which a value of y is assigned to values of x constitutes a function. In some theoretical investigations, the wide generality or vagueness of the function concept is, in fact, an advantage. However, for applications, particularly in the calculus, the general concept of function is unnecessarily wide. To make meaningful mathematical developments possible, the "arbitrary" laws of correspondence by which a value of y is assigned to x must be subjected to radical restrictions. During the past century and a half mathematicians have recognized and formulated in precise terms the essential restrictions that have to be imposed on the overly general concept in order to obtain functions that indeed have the useful properties one would expect intuitively."

I began wondering, what kind of properties does a function need to have to be "useful" in calculus? And, more importantly, what is the impact of those properties in the subject?

Comment: For example, the domains of such functions should be topological spaces.

Comment: I think Courant was simply referring to the fact that most theorems require some continuity or differentiability or other assumptions on the functions. There are very few nontrivial results for arbitrary functions, even from the reals to the reals (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/231462/15780) for a rare exception). If you look at the theorem statements involving one or more functions in Courant/John (or in any real analysis or advanced calculus text), you'll see that virtually all of them involve certain restrictions on the functions involved.